# Failed to execute db.system.keys.find() via root, how can this collection be find()?

Tags: mongodb

**MongoDB version is 4.0.3**

**Root user has been created via**

```
db.createUser({user:"root",pwd:"arthur",roles:[{role:"root",db:"admin"}]})
```

Via listCollections or db.getCollectionInfos(), three collections as list,

```
system.users
system.version
system.keys
```

'Not authorized' info would be shown when find() on system.keys. And another two collections are without any error.

I'm not sure anything missing/wrong for user creation or others. How can I handle this error. Look forward to your help.

How can I get details about this collection
which is not mentioned in document
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/system-collections/

**Console print as below**

```
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> use admin
switched to db admin
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.auth("root","arthur")
1
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.runCommand( { listCollections: 1.0, authorizedCollections: true, nameOnly: true } )
{
    "cursor" : {
        "id" : NumberLong(0),
        "ns" : "admin.$cmd.listCollections",
        "firstBatch" : [ ]
    },
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1541747273, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1541747273, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"FnDH1ejRM/2TfV+0WiPFqH0KIMk="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6621746286506803230")
        }
    }
}
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.runCommand( { listCollections: 1.0, nameOnly: true } )
{
    "cursor" : {
        "id" : NumberLong(0),
        "ns" : "admin.$cmd.listCollections",
        "firstBatch" : [
            {
                "name" : "system.users",
                "type" : "collection"
            },
            {
                "name" : "system.version",
                "type" : "collection"
            },
            {
                "name" : "system.keys",
                "type" : "collection"
            }
        ]
    },
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1541747273, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1541747273, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"FnDH1ejRM/2TfV+0WiPFqH0KIMk="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6621746286506803230")
        }
    }
}
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.system.keys.find()
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { find: \"system.keys\", filter: {}, lsid: { id: UUID(\"a7884ca5-0f46-4906-8a15-955bbd74d2ae\") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1541747273, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 1670C7D5E8D133FD937D5FB45A23C5A87D0A20C9), keyId: 6621746286506803230 } }, $db: \"admin\" }",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized",
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1541747273, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1541747273, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"FnDH1ejRM/2TfV+0WiPFqH0KIMk="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6621746286506803230")
        }
    }
}
MongoDB Enterprise mongos>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only "backup" and "__system" can operate this table

```
db.system.keys.find()/count()       <====   "__system" role only
other operations (not verify all)   <====   "backup" and "__system" role
```

does any one share the detail about this collection.
thanks